# ACL users to change write permissions

Tags: access-control-list, groups

I’m trying to set up an environment in which multiple users can work on a single website project. In addition, every one should be able to grant additional write permissions for apache.

The idea is that everyone uses a separate login (lets assume it’s `joe`, `jane` and `mark` in the group `users`) . The apache is running as `apache:www`. Everyone has to have write permissions to all the files, apache has read only access. Now, files chosen by the users have to be writable by apache (it’s important that apache cannot have write permissions to all the files — security concerns).

I’ve tried two setups, one using ACL-s, one using umask, common group, etc. Both have the same flaw — users cannot change write permissions for apache.

The two approaches I tried:

- `setfacl -m default:group:users:rwx project/`

  This way it’s easy for me to manage write permissions for all the users. No additional setup, just works. Whatever the file owner is, every user of the team can modify the file. Unfortunately, only the file owner can add write permissions for `apache`
- `umask 0002` in `.bashrc`, all users in the same group

  Basing on simple permissions, every user has read and write access to all the files. `chgrp www ...` is needed for apache to have write permissions. Again — only the file owner can do this.

So I’m basically looking for a way to grant multiple users the permission to do a `g+w` on a file. I thought of other ways of doing it, for example:

- bash script to change permissions, ran by sudo. Could work, but it’s a security issue. It’s quite complicated for me to restrict it’s access to the project directory only. Even if I do, there will be complications with recursive mode and so on.
- directory structure like this:

  - /project/www - the apache htdocs (`setfacl -m d:group:users:rwx`)
  - /project/data - writable by apache (`setfacl -m d:user:apache:rwx`)
  - whatever in the `./www` directory has to be writable by `apache`, has to be created in `./data` and symlinked — but that’s neither elegant or convenient

So I’m looking for a solution that’s easy to use. The initial setup may be complicated, but the every-day use shouldn’t. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing allows the non-owning, non-root user to change file permissions.  I'd go with the sudo'd script -- I don't see what's so hard about it, though.  Use `readlink -f` to canonicalize the filename to change so you can check it's prefix is correct, don't let the user actually specify the permissions, just make it a "grant write access to Apache" script.

Comment: yeah, it seems you’re right. chown doesn’t traverse symlinks by default, so simple prefix check should do the job.

Comment: More than that, though, readlink -f makes sure that there are no symlinks in the path by canonicalising the path.